# Unable to find email alert in workflows

Tags: email-alert

I am unable to find the workflow to stop email alerts since there are many workflows.

Please let me know if there is another way to stop the email alert.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, No. Yo will have to find the offending workflow and deactivate it.

Some tips:

> Start at the email alert level and not the workflow rule

1. Create list views per object for workflows and email alerts
2. Start at the email alerts and find the one that is sending the email
3. Click on it
4. In the related list of the detail view it will provide a link to the workflow rule(s) using the alert
5. Click on those links and deactivate as appropriate.

> Use and IDE or your choice to search for the email alert / workflow rule via a text search

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a repeatable use case that is spamming out these email alerts, turn the debug log on with `Workflow INFO`

The debug log will show which workflows triggered with entry conditions met and then you can hone in on the issue (search for `WF_EMAIL_ALERT` and then work upwards in the log)

[image]